# What's the best way to set up a fresh OS install?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, operating-systems

My computer is deathly slow so I'm reinstalling Windows 7. However, I'd like to know the best way to set up the file system.

Previously, I just installed it and used it. I was told by a friend that I should have the OS on a separate partition and that I shouldn't be storing Steam files, etc. in the C:\ folder.

Is there an optimal way to install Windows 7 and if so, how much space should I allocate and where do I put huge folders like Steam?

Comment: Boot into the installation media of your choice and install the operating system.  While you can make separate partitions, trying to configure Windows to place application data like Steam on another partition other then the system partition, is not an easy task.  There are tons of existing material on how to configure Windows to do this though.

Comment: In my personal experience, the benefits you will get out of doing what Ramhound said, are not that great.  My personal set up is using a SSD for the OS and software I use, and then other "data" drives are just standard spinning hard drives.  The use of an SSD has been just about the single best performance enhancer I've seen for improving performance.

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames - Doing what the author wants when a SSD is being is an entirely different story.  With a mechanical drive there is no real significant reason to do what the author is asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: your friend is right.
The benefits of having your operating system on another partition are multiple. For example, when you decide to install another operating system instead of Win7 (such as Win8) you don't have to backup all your files since they're on a different partition.
When I re-install operating systems, I give the OS 100GB. It's quite enough for the operating system, any required frameworks and programs (such as Visual Studio requiring space on the windows drive) and I still have space left on it. So,

- The OS gets 100GB.
- The second partition is the rest of the space available on the HDD. All programs let you change where you install them, so that's fine.

However, the user folders such as `My Documents`, `My Music` et cetera are installed by default to the C: drive. So, you need to move them to the other partition so it doesn't fill up your OS drive.